# Inspect Json::Value from JsonCpp in VS2017 Debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, jsoncpp

I'm using the JsonCpp library. Previously, in VS 2015, it was possible to inspect the contents of a Json::objectValue with the debugger. It was shown as a std::map somewhere in the containing class (I even used a visualizer). However this is not the case anymore in VS 2017. There is still a

```
std::map<Json::Value::CZString, Json::Value>
```

but I cannot inspect it anymore. I looked at maps that I create directly and there everything is fine. Anyone has a clue?
BR,
Daniel

**Edit:**
[image]

There were no extensions installed in VS2015 that seemed to be related. I tried installing some under VS2017 though, but without any effect on the problem.

Comment: Could you share the detailed steps about how do you inspect the contents in Visual Studio 2015? Please check whether you installed any Visual Studio extensions in VS2015 to help you inspect the content.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio 2017 do you use? I checked my VS2017 Enterprise version 15.4.4, it works fine in it. Please reset your Visual Studio settings if you have changed settings before. And also check what C++ related components installed for your Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional (just upgraded to 15.4.4). The problem is still there. I even build the latest JsonCpp, since we were using a rather old version, but to no success.

Comment: I clone this JsonCpp library sample project (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) and add your code into the main.cpp file in test_lib_json project, it works fine. Please try this project in your Visual Studio, if it works fine in your Visual Studio, there should be some problem on your project. Please compare your project with this one to check what happened in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your help Wendy. You are right. If I do it like this it works fine. I did clone the same repo yesterday, build the lib and tried do use it in another solution. Must be something with my pre-build lib or whatever. I'll continue investigating.